# Python Qt5: System tray menu stops working after clicking a button

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I run the program, the system tray icon appears and the menu works, but when I click Start Dice Bot/Stop Dice Bot then the menu stops working, I right-click on it but nothing happens, no errors or crashes.
PS If I click the exit button it works fine.

After doing some testing I think it's related to async def coroutines.

## sysTrayApp.py

```
#sysTrayApp.py

from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from diceBot import startClient, stopClient
  
  
app = QApplication([])
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
  
# Adding an icon
icon = QIcon("icon.png")
  
# Adding item on the menu bar
tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
tray.setIcon(icon)
tray.setVisible(True)
  
# Creating the options
menu = QMenu()

startBot = QAction("Start Dice Bot")
stopBot = QAction("Stop Dice Bot")

startBot.triggered.connect(startClient)
stopBot.triggered.connect(stopClient)

menu.addAction(startBot)
menu.addAction(stopBot)

# To quit the app
quit = QAction("Quit")
quit.triggered.connect(app.quit)
menu.addAction(quit)

# Adding options to the System Tray
tray.setContextMenu(menu)

  
app.exec_()
```

## diceBot.py

```
# diceBot.py

#?--- Imports ---
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Client, Intents 
from discord.utils import get
from diceBot_Functions import diceFunction

#?--- Intents ---
intents = Intents.default() 
intents.members = True 

#?--- Imports the data from .env's ---
load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN') 

#?--- Variables ---
commandPrefix = "!"

#?--- Init' Client ---
client = Client(intents=intents)

#?--- Events ---
#* on_ready() event
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user.name} has connected to the following servers:\n") 
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(f"Name: {guild.name}, ID: {guild.id}")

#* on_message() event
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    #* Stops the bot responding to it's self
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    #* Dice Function
    elif message.content.lower().startswith(commandPrefix + "dice"):
        await diceFunction(message)

    #elif message.author.display_name == "pugstorm" :
        #emoji = get(message.guild.emojis, name="sankethunk")
        #await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        #await message.channel.send("Turn Fighter!")

#?--- Run Client ---
def startClient():
    client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)

def stopClient():
    client.logout()
```

## diceBot_Functions.py

````
#diceBot_Functions.py
#?---Imports---
from random import randint
from discord import Embed, Color

async def diceFunction(message):
    #?---User Input---
    diceInput = message.content 
    diceInput = diceInput.partition("!dice") [2]
    diceInput = diceInput.upper()

    #?---Variables---
    diceLst = []
    diceDict = {}
    operatorLst = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]
    operator = ""
    operatorNum = ""
    operatorAns = ""
    emb = Embed()

    #?---Main Loop---
    for die in diceInput.split(", "):
        match = next((x for x in operatorLst if x in die), False)
        if match:
            operator = match
            operatorNum = int(die.partition(operator)[2])
        else:
            diceLst.append(die)

    for item in diceLst:
        diceAmount = int(item.partition("D") [0])
        diceSides = int(item.partition("D") [2])
        diceType = "D" + str(diceSides)

        diceDict[diceType] = [diceAmount, diceSides]

    #print(f"Throw Operator: {operator} {operatorNum}")
    #print("Dice Dictionary:")
    for item in diceDict:
        diceLst.append(item)

    throwTotal = 0
    for key in diceDict: 
        #print(f"Throwing: {key}")
        diceAmount = diceDict[key][0]
        diceSides = diceDict[key][1]
        #print(f"Throw Amount: {diceAmount}")
        #print(f"Dice Sides: {diceSides}")

        throwLst = []
        for i in range(diceAmount):
            throwVal = randint(1, diceSides)
            #print(f"Throw value: {throwVal}\n")
            throwTotal += throwVal
            throwVal = str(throwVal)
            throwLst.append(throwVal)
            #emb.add_field(name = f"{key} Roll {i + 1}", value = throwVal, inline=True)
        throwLstStr = ", ".join(throwLst)
        emb.add_field(name = f"{key}", value = f"{throwLstStr}", inline=True)
    
    #?---Final Results---
    diceInput = diceInput.replace(':', ' : ')
    emb.color = Color.orange()
    emb.set_author(name =  f"{message.author.display_name} Rolled: {diceInput}", icon_url = message.author.avatar_url)
    
    if operator != "":
        if operator == "+":
            operatorAns = throwTotal + operatorNum
        elif operator == "-":
            operatorAns = throwTotal - operatorNum
        elif operator == "/":
            operatorAns = throwTotal / operatorNum
        elif operator == "*":
            operatorAns = throwTotal * operatorNum


        emb.description = f"Total Throw Value: {throwTotal}\nThrow Operator: {throwTotal} {operator} {operatorNum}\nFinal Throw Value: **{operatorAns}**"
        await message.channel.send(embed=emb)
    
    else:
        emb.description = f"Final Throw Value: **{throwTotal}**"
        await message.channel.send(embed=emb)
    ```
````

Comment: TYPO: `startBot.triggered.connect(startClient())` -> `startBot.triggered.connect(startClient)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry i was testing stuff, it still stops working without the ()
Updated original post

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (specifically, your code used `startClient` and `stopClient`, but there's no reference to them).

Comment: @musicamante sure, i didn't want to spam with code, updated post

Comment: @musicamante You still need a .env and a discord bot token in it to make it run though which I obviously can't put here.

Comment: Explaining that you were using an external library (and how) should've been noted since the beginning. A MRE doesn't have to include *all your code*, only the parts required to understand and eventually reproduce the issue. Besides, as the documentation clearly says, [`client.run()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.run) is "A blocking call": it completely blocks everything (including the Qt event loop, which, among other important things, is responsible of properly processing of user events). Use `start()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, its my first time posting on SO :)

So I added client.run(), and turned them into async/await functions, and called them in the sysTrayApp
# diceBot.py
`async def startClient():
    await client.start(DISCORD_TOKEN)

async def stopClient(): #? Maybe use close instead of logout
    await client.logout()
`
But now I get this error when pressing the "Start Dice Bot" button
`sysTrayApp.py:41: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'startClient' was never awaited
  app.exec_()`
I tried making `app.exec_()` a async def/await function but then the sysTrayApp doesn't start.

Comment: @SnakeDoc (please use `@username`) why do you need to use await/async? That client already runs in a separate thread. Besides, the application is created and executed in the main thread, you should not touch it. (Note: since you just joined SO, please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and always review the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/2001654) before posting until you're experienced enough with the site).